# Material UI AutoComplete clear the value on select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to clear the value that is selected in the input filed right after a selection made.
It is being cleared on blur but not on select.

```
<Autocomplete
  disabled={showTextField}
  className="center-vertically"
  options={listOfDependencies.sort()}
  style={{ width: 500 }}
  onChange={addDependency}
  value={value}
  onKeyPress={(event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      addDependency;
    }
  }}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      value={value}
      label="Select dependency"
      variant="outlined"
      defaultValue={[listOfDependencies[0]]}
      fullWidth
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a filter on the `options` data would be fine

```
const [select, setSelect] = React.useState(null);
const addDependency = (e, value) => {
  setSelect(value)
}

options={listOfDependencies.filter(x => !select || select.title !== x.title)}
```

Full code could be found in the online demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mppyj9?file=demo.js

[image]